# spring boot logging issue

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, logback

I am new to SpringBoot Project, I am trying to configure `logback-spring.xml`

Logging Dependencies in my project `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Logging Configuration in `application.proerties`:

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-spring.xml
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

When I run the executable war, it throws below exceptions:

```
  SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/target/rentacoder.war!/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/target/rentacoder.war!/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 16
    log4j:WARN Document root element "configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 16
    log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    log4j:WARN The <configuration> element has been deprecated.
    log4j:WARN Use the <log4j:configuration> element instead.
    log4j:WARN Unrecognized element include
    log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

My `logback-spring.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>myApp.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache.velocity" level="OFF" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Can someone shed some light on this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems.

Firstly, to use `logback-spring.xml` to configure your logging, you need to be using Logback yet you've excluded `spring-boot-starter-logging` which uses Logback in favour of `spring-boot-starter-log4j` which uses Log4j. If you want to use `logback-spring.xml` you should remove the exclusion from your pom.

Secondly, `SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/target/rentacoder.war!/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]` means that you also have `slf4j-simple` on the class path. I can't tell where it's coming from given the information you've provided but you need to remove it from your dependencies. You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to help you to determine where it's coming from and remove/exclude it as appropriate.

Comment: I use `mvn dependency:tree` and find that `slf4j-simple` is from dependency postgresql